# Powershell Array funnction

Tags: arrays, powershell-3.0

I am running below script and retrieve information from the template and assign permission. Here I would like to get the User as array input my below script is not processing the user as array.

```
$userObj = [PSCustomObject]((Get-Content -Raw C:\txt\sample.txt) -replace ':','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData)

[array]$userObj.User

for ($i[0]; $userObj.user; $i++) {
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $userObj.Identity -User $userObj.User -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -confirm:$false
}
```

Here is my text input which is converted as custom object

[image]

Comment: Why image in question?

Comment: That is is the notepad format which will be read and converted as custom ps object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$userObj.User` is a string with comma-separated names. Casting it to an array just gives you an array with one string with comma-separated names, not an array of the names.

`[array]$userObj.User` ⇒ `[ 'auto,auto1' ]`
`[array]$userObj.User` ⇏ `[ 'auto', 'auto1' ]`

To get an array of the names from the comma-separated string you need to split it:

```
$userObj.User -split ','
```

Also, your `for` loop is broken. Those loops have the following structure:

```
for (loop variable initialization; condition; loop variable incrementation)
```

e.g.

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++)
```

But you probably don't need a `for` loop here anyway. If you want to run a command for each element of the array resulting from your split operation use a `ForEach-Object` instead:

```
$userObj.User -split ',' | ForEach-Object {
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $userObj.Identity -User $_ ...
}
```